# R ttest inside ddply gives error "grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels"

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataframe with several factors and two phenotypes

```
freq sampleID status score snpsincluded
0.5 0001 case 100 all 
0.2 0001 case 30 all 
0.5 0002 control 110 all 
0.5 0003 case 100 del 
etc
```

I would like to do a t.test comparing cases and controls for each set of relevant factors. I have tried the following:

```
o2 <- ddply(df, c("freq","snpsincluded"), summarise, pval=t.test(score, status)$p.value)
```

but it complains that "  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels"

I have no missing values, NAs, and Ive checked:

```
levels(df$status)
[1] "case"    "control"
```

Am I missing something stupid? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error because , you get a for at least one sub-group ,  **unique status** value for all  **score**'s.

This reproduce the error, the status is unique (equal to 1) for all scores.

```
dx = read.table(text='   score status
1 1 1 
2 2 1 
3 3 1 ')

t.test(score ~ status, data = dx) 
Error in t.test.formula(score ~ status, data = dx) : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

this correct the problem but create another known problem with `t.test`, you should have enough observations( I think >= 2):

```
dx = read.table(text='   score status
1 1 1 
2 2 1 
3 3 2 ')

t.test(score ~ status, data = dx) 
Error in t.test.default(x = 1:2, y = 3L) : not enough 'y' observations
```

Finally this correct all the problems:

```
dx = read.table(text='   score status
1 1 1 
2 2 1 
3 3 2 
4 4 2')

t.test(score ~ status, data = dx) 

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  score by status
t = -2.8284, df = 2, p-value = 0.1056
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -5.042435  1.042435
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
            1.5             3.5
```

**EDIT**  I explain the problem without giving a solution, because you don't give a reproducible example.

one solution is  do computation only for good groups:

```
  ddply(df, c("freq","snpsincluded"), function(x)
      { 
       if(length(unique(x$status)==2)
         pval=t.test(score~status,data=x)$p.value
     })
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I'm not sure I understand "you get a unique status value for all score's" though: I have about 700 lines for both cases and controls. Also, I should add, I have a few more factors I left out for clarity, but those are the reason I do not like to do t-test on data subsets for each combination. If I do ttest of the whole dataset (without considering factors) it works.  Again, thanks for help.

Comment: @madieke I add some comments to clarify this. Better to see my example 's.